# Is there a better way to "lock" a Port as a semaphore in Dart than this example?

Tags: dart

Is it possible in Dart to “lock” a Port other than by starting a server on that Port. In other words I guess, the Port is acting as a semaphore. Alternatively is there another way to achieve the same result?

I posted a question asking for a solution to this problem, and Fox32 suggested starting a server on a specific Port, and in that way determine if another instance of the program is already running. I need to determine the first instance to start actual processing rather than whether actually just running, and that solution works.

While that solution works well, it appears to me that there should be a more tailored solution. Example code is below:

```
/*
 * Attempt to connect to specific port to determine if first process.
 */
async.Future<bool> fTestIfFirstInstance() {

  async.Completer<bool> oCompleter = new async.Completer<bool>();

  const String S_HOST = "127.0.0.1"; // ie: localhost 
  const int    I_PORT = 8087;

  HttpServer.bind(S_HOST, I_PORT).then((oHtServer) {
    ogHtServer = oHtServer;        // copy to global
    oCompleter.complete(true);     // this is the first process
    return;
  }).catchError((oError) {
    oCompleter.complete(false);    // this is NOT the first process
    return;
  });
  return oCompleter.future;
}
```

Comment: You could use a tcp socket instead of a http server.

Comment: Ok, I'll look at that. Http did seem overkill, but I haven't used a tcp socket previously. On reflection, my code is rather verbose also. I have cut it down. I think the VM must go through first to pick up the future and then run the code async and therefore for starters, the two "return"s are not needed because the final return will be executed after the async code "again". I was planning to find a better solution than Http and possibly writing something at a lower level if feasible just to lock the Port. It does do the trick though and works seamlessly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm unsure whether this (RawServerSocket) is any "better" than the HttpServer solution, however perhaps it makes more sense.

I think that a means to simply "lock" the Port and unlock the Port would be worthwhile. It provides a good means of using a semaphore IMHO.

```
/*
 * Attempt to connect to specific port to determine if first process.
 */
async.Future<bool> fTestIfFirstInstance() {
  async.Completer<bool> oCompleter = new async.Completer<bool>(); 
  RawServerSocket.bind("127.0.0.1", 8087).then((oSocket) {
    ogSocket = oSocket;         // assign to global
    oCompleter.complete(true);
  }).catchError((oError) {
    oCompleter.complete(false);
  });

  return oCompleter.future;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is often done by using a file, e.g. '/tmp/my_program.lock' or '~/.my_program.lock' depending on global or per-user lock.

I dart in would be as simple as:

```
bool isRunning() {
  return new File(lockPath).existsSync();
}
```

Starting:

```
void createLock() {
  if (isRunning()) throw "Lock file '$lockPath' exists, program may be running";
  new File(lockPath).createSync();
}
```

And when closing the program:

```
void deleteLock() {
  new File(lockPath).deleteSync();
}
```

Something to remember is that while the HttpServer will be closed when the program closes, the file won't be deleted. This can be worked around by writing the programs PID to the lock file when creating the file, and check if the PID is alive in `isRunning`. If it's not alive, delete the file and return false.

Comment: Thanks Anders. It's nice to know another way to achieve this. However I wouldn't say it's necessarily better IMHO. Perhaps Dart could provide something in the future to achieve this more elegantly.